# Creating a Parse Role Hierarchy fails with 'parent is undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, roles

I get a strange error when setting up a role hierarchy in `Parse`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: parent is not defined

The roles are all created ok in Parse, and the relation objects I get from `getRoles` look ok, but when calling the `add` method I get this error. Anyone else experiencing something similar?

Here's the code (running parse@1.6.3, the parse/node implementation):

```js
function createRolesForOrganization(organization){
  var self = Parse.User.current();
  var ownerRole = new Parse.Role(organization.id + '_Owner', new Parse.ACL(self)),
      adminRole = new Parse.Role(organization.id + '_Admin', new Parse.ACL(self)),
      userRole = new Parse.Role(organization.id + '_User', new Parse.ACL(self));

  return Parse.Object
    .saveAll([
      ownerRole, 
      adminRole, 
      userRole
    ])
    .then(function(objs){
      ownerRole = objs[0];          
      adminRole = objs[1];
      userRole = objs[2];

      userRole.getRoles().add(adminRole);
      adminRole.getRoles().add(ownerRole);

      return Parse.Object.saveAll([
        ownerRole, 
        adminRole, 
        userRole
      ]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Parse JavaScript SDK that is reported here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677477152487599/

A quick fix in the meantime is to replace 'parent' with 'this.parent' on line 101 in ParseRelation.js, or roll back to a version before 1.6.

Comment: How do you change ParseRelation.js if you're using the Command line tool?

Comment: @natecraft1 Not possible if you're running on Parse servers, only if you're using the Parse SDK in your own Node.js environment. But now they've fixed it!